# Quickly changing outline color of polygon in ArcGIS Desktop without opening Symbol Selector?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, color

In ArcGIS Desktop 10, I know it's possible to quick change the fill color of a polygon by right-clicking the symbol box of any layer and just pick a simple fill color.

Is there a way to change the outline without open the "Symbol Selector" window?

[image: How to change outline color without this window?]

---

Sei que é possível alterar a cor de um preenchimento clicando com o botão direito na caixa do símbolo de qualquer layer e aí basta escolher uma com simples.

Tem como alterar o contorno do polígono sem abrir a janela "Symbol Selector"?

Answer (score 3):

I find it quick enough. Not sure it can be any quicker other then just the few clicks it requires. If the styles take some time to load then you can speed it up by only keeping the bare basics and removing all complex styles from the Style Manager. I know you want to be able to change the outlines "quicker" but another option might be to create a style beforehand and give it a unique name then if the layer you are loading into the map has the same name the layer will "inherit" that particular symbol.

Beyond this there is customization (add-ins) with ArcObjects and Visual Studio .Net. You can create any tool you can think up. It would not be difficult for example (if you have some programming experience) to create a tool with some default presets for changing the outline thickness and colour.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This isn't really a big problem. I have some saved styles and just thought that this would be a useful shortcut to learn.

Once I have no programming skill, I think the standard way will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out **Apply Symbology From Layer (Data Management)** [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006n000000).

Summary

> This tool applies the symbology from a layer to the Input Layer. It
>   can be applied to feature, raster, network analysis, and TIN layer
>   files or layers in the ArcMap table of contents. This tool is
>   primarily for use in scripts or ModelBuilder.

[image: symb]

Example Code from Esri Doc:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set the current workspace
env.workspace = "C:/data"

# Set layer to apply symbology to
inputLayer = "sf_points.lyr"

# Set layer that output symbology will be based on
symbologyLayer = "water_symbols_pnt.lyr"

# Apply the symbology from the symbology layer to the input layer
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (inputLayer, symbologyLayer)
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Can't say it won't help but my question is for change the outline color of a single polygon using a shortcut or  any other quick method (shift+right-click as an example). Thank you!

Comment: the question is for change the outline color of a single polygon using a shortcut or any other quick method